# Excluding particular array object before sorting in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to exlcude (not remove) particular object and then sort nest array object in javascript,
Below function that sorts array object. i need to exclude the objects that is not having amount property and then sort the object having only amount in javascript and map the object(need to use exluded obj and sorted obj).

```
this.providerList = [{id:"transferwise", amount:"1000"}, {id:"wordlremit", amount:"4000", {id:"instarem", amount:"3000"}, {country: "Singapore", scn: "SG"}, {country: "India", scn: "IN"}];
```

```
 sortAndFilterProviders() {
    let myList = [];
    myList = [...this.providerList];
    myList.push.apply(myList, this.apiproviderdata.apiproviders);
    // var mergeList = myList.concat(this.query);
    // console.log(mergeList);
    myList.sort(function (a, b) {
      var a1 = a.amount, b1 = b.amount;
      if (a1 == b1) return 0;
      return a1 > b1 ? 1 : -1;
    });
    this.providerList = [...myList];
    return this.providerList;
  }
```

```
expected output
  country: Singapore, India
  Sorted Amount : Transferwise , Instarem, Worldremit
```

Comment: *i need to exclude the objects that is not having amount property and then sort the object having only amount*...is not quite clear. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Mamun the expected output:   country: Singapore, India
  Sorted Amount : Transferwise , Instarem, Worldremit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to create the arrays with/without the property. Then sort the desired array. Finally [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them like the following way:

```js
let providerList = [{id:"transferwise", amount:"1000"}, {id:"wordlremit", amount:"4000"}, {id:"instarem", amount:"3000"}, {country: "Singapore", scn: "SG"}, {country: "India", scn: "IN"}];

let amount = providerList.filter( item => item.hasOwnProperty('amount')).sort((a,b)=> a.amount - b.amount);
let notAmount = providerList.filter( item => !item.hasOwnProperty('amount'));
var res = notAmount.concat(amount)
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first filter `myList` into two lists based on whether each element has the `amount` property:

```
const includesAmount = myList.filter(item => item.hasOwnProperty('amount'));
const excludesAmount = myList.filter(item => !item.hasOwnProperty('amount'));
includesAmount.sort(...)

const finalArray = [...includesAmount, ...excludesAmount];
```

This makes two passes through `myList`, but you can do it in one pass by iterating through `myList` and pushing each element to its respective array.

Comment: thanks for prompt reply, but i have to use exlcude value in map also, in filteredlist i will have only sorted objects but i need to sort  as well as have excluded objects since i need to use map function

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the above answers must make use of `hasOwnProperty()`.

It is simply shorter and more readable to simply check if that property exist:

```
sortAndFilterProviders() {
  const noAmountList = myList(item => !item['amount']);
  const amountList = myList(item => item['amount']);

  amountList.sort( (a, b) => {
    const a1 = a.amount, 
    b1 = b.amount;
    if (a1 == b1) {
      return 0;
    };
    return a1 > b1 ? 1 : -1;
   });

   console.log(amountList); // check if it is sorted
   return [... noAmountList, amountList];
 }
```

Comment: I believe that will filter out all falsy values (0, empty strings, etc) which might result in unexpected and hard to debug behavior

Comment: @miyu Ah that is true..! Sorry about that, you are actually right